# Loading a promise into an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, protractor

I have an array of names that is displayed to console like this:

```js
myLists.count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myLists.get(i).getWebElement());
    myLists.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
    });
  }
});
```

On my page the names are able to be sorted ascending or descending depending if you choose a filter option.  I'd like to read the myLists array into a variable array so I can reverse the order and compare it when filtered. I'm not too sure how to do this as i'm new to angularjs and my java/js code clearly isn't going to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question i understand that you are already able to read myLists array and print the output to the console. To copy it into another array all you have to do is to copy the myLists array into variable array and then sort them. Here's an example code below -

```
var varArray; //declare variable array
myLists.map(function(myListArray){
  return myListArray.getText().then(function(mylist){
    return mylist;
  });
}).then(function(mylist){

  //copy myLists array into varArray
  varArray = mylist;

  //Sort the variable array in ascending order use the below function
  varArray = varArray.sort();
  expect(varArray).toEqual(mylist); //check for the equality of array

  //Reverse sort variable array in descending order
  varArray = varArray.reverse();
  expect(varArray).toEqual(mylist); //check for the equality of array
});
```

Both reverse() and sort() are inbuilt javascript functions. However use sort before reverse as the reverse() method just reverses the order of the elements in an array.

To scroll the page to a particular element use the below javascript command -

```
var ele = yourElement;
var eleLoc;
ele.getLocation().then(function(loc){
  eleLoc = loc; //get the element location in a variable
});
//Scroll to the element location
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo('+eleLoc.x+','+eleLoc.y+');')
.then(function(){
  //try getting the text here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would need the map to scroll down element by element or I cannot read the elements in.

Comment: You cannot scroll down element by element using map function. You can use javascript function to scroll down each element for which you are getting the text. Updated the answer with scroll function.

Comment: Hi Nicole Philips, getLocation() function in protractor returns an object of loc.x and loc.y. Here's the link of its usage - [getLocation function](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getLocation). Your element is either not present in DOM or its not loaded yet. Try waiting for the element to load and then get its location.